# Global variables in class and outside class

Tags: php, variables, global-variables

I'll explain this shortly:

```
class num
{
    function num1()
    {
        global $error;
        $error="This is an error message";
        return false;
    }

    function num2()
    {
        global $error;
        return $error;
    }
}

$num=new num();
$check=$num->num1();
if($check===false) $error.="There is another error message";

die($error);//This is an error messageThere is another error message
```

`$error` in the function `num1` affect `$error` outside the class. Any suggestions on how i can prevent this?

Comment: You are missing semicolon, in the end of return false statement

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't the question i wanted to get answered :D But thank you.

Comment: Well I suppose its because you use global. Stop that and it wont effect the $error outside your object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use object fields (properties):

```
class num
{
    protected $error;

    public function num1()
    {
        $this->error = "This is an error message";
        return false;
    }

    public function num2()
    {
        return $this->error;
    }
}

$num = new num();
$check = $num->num1();
if ($check===false) {
    // $error is just local variable, not defined before
    $error .= "There is another error message";

    // $objError is the error message from object
    $objError = $num->num2();
}
```

Global variables are antipattern. One of the priciples of OO is encapsulation. You don't want to expose the $error variable, unless there is a method (contract) returning it. Which is exactly what you can do with private or protected properties.

I recommend you reading some of this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Also, consider beter class, method and variable names. `num1` and `num2` are one of the worst you might have chosen. But I understand this is an example.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! And i can finally get rid of the `global $error` in all functions :-D

Comment: If this is new to you (and it helped), you really *should* read some basics of OOP (the link I have posted). That will open a new world to you. You are welcome.

Comment: I will, thank you. PHP for me is like the universe, It's infinity!